# update statement using self join condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table call EMPLOYEE, which contains supervisor_id and employee_id. I am trying to update one of the employee(114) supervisor (100), to become the supervisor for 114 employees.

| Employee_id | Supervisor_id |
| --- | --- |
| 114 | 100 |
| 115 | 114 |
| 116 | 114 |
| 117 | 114 |
| 118 | 114 |
| 119 | 114 |

I tried using this update statement:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE AS E1
JOIN (SELECT employee_id 
FROM EMPLOYEE
     WHERE supervisor_id = 114) AS E2
     SET E1.supervisor_id = E2.employee_id
     WHERE E1.supervisor_id = 114;
```

But it printed 115 as the supervisor_id, when it was supposed to print 110. Is there anything wrong with the statement?
Note: I can only use update statement only.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is your expected result based on the data provided ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha im trying to change 115 - 119 supervisor_id from 114 to 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion, before executing an `update` with `inner join` try the same query  using `select` statement to view the rows returned.
In your case you can't use  `update` with  `join` because the condition `supervisor_id = 114` will remove the value of  `supervisor_id=100` .

You should use subquery ,but in `update` or `delete` you cant specify the same table , so you should wrap the subquery into an outer query giving the table an alias.

> This nested query  is not very good for performance.

Try:

```
update employee set supervisor_id= ( select t.supervisor_id 
                                     from ( SELECT supervisor_id 
                                            FROM   employee 
                                            WHERE  employee_id = 114
                                             ) as t 
                                    )
where  supervisor_id=114;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qff694udysNgqbyJyFcDzn/8

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I feel is that your join operation is giving some different output, can you try to join on table entry like below:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE AS E1
JOIN (SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE 
     WHERE supervisor_id = 114) AS E2
     SET E1.supervisor_id = E2.employee_id
     WHERE E1.supervisor_id = 114;
```

Comment: And what did you change from the `OP` query? It seems to me that is the same query

Comment: yea i just ran it, it gave the same result